# ParseFile progress callback broken

Tags: android, parse-platform, progress

I'm using parse android library and everything is working great. But the progress callback for saving ParseFile seems to be broken. It only updates at 0 or 100%. Which of course is of no use if you want to show progress update. Can someone from parse give an eta for this fix. It's been already two years since you guys confirmed it as a bug on old community forum on parse.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report. Please direct bug reports to https://parse.com/help#report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in 1.8.3 [Parse Downloads](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads)

Answer (score -1):

Agreed. Two years with no word is insane.  Especially considering the resources they have after being purchased by facebook.  Fix it!